# Elixir - Merging two maps with similar key names and values as lists?

Tags: list, nested, maps, elixir, concatenation

I have two maps:

```
a = %{ list: [1,2,3]}
b = %{ list: [4,5,6]}
```

I wish to merge/concat the two nested lists, such that the result is:

```
c = %{ list: [1,2,3,4,5,6]}
```

I've tried looking into deep merge, but in my case I have lists rather than nested maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the `++` operator for concatenating lists

```
iex(1)> a = %{ list: [1,2,3]}
iex(2)> b = %{ list: [4,5,6]}
iex(3)> %{list:  a.list ++ b.list}
%{list: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]}
```

more generic:

```
  def test_merge do
    a = %{ list: [1,2,3], list2: [10, 20]}
    b = %{ list2: [40, 30], list: [4,5,6]}
    keys = Map.keys(a)
    Enum.map(keys ,fn(key) -> {key, a[key] ++  b[key] }end) 
    |> Enum.into(%{})
  end
```

result:

`%{list: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], list2: [10, 20, 40]}`

Answer (score 5):

You can also use [Map.merge/3](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#merge/3) to easily handle this case.  Check it out:

```
a = %{ list: [1,2,3] }
b = %{ list: [4,5,6] }
c = Map.merge(a, b, fn _, la, lb -> la ++ lb end)
```

Enjoy!